# Camera permission granted is not updated when button is Clicked

Tags: java, android

sorry it might be a trivial question for you but I couldn't do it so bear with me. I'm creating this fragment layout where users will be welcome with a button. If users click the button( named; camera) then the app should display a pop-up message to grant or deny the camera permission. If the permission is granted then the button should slide and hide. If denied then display a toast message. Right now, I'm able to display the pop-up message to ask for the permission but when a user grants the permission it doesn't slide the button and hide. But when I click the button again it will slide and hide. It looks like when I call the manageCameraPerm() method it doesn't update instantly. Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thank you.

Here's my fragment class

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cameraPerm:
                manageCameraPerm();
                if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

                    v.startAnimation(animSlide);
                    allowCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    w = 1;
                }
                break;
     }
 }
```

// Here is my manageCameraPerm method

```
 private void manageCameraPerm() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMS_REQUEST_CAMERA);


        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Camera is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using a device that's Marshmallow or higher, you have to handle the UI code (animating and then hiding the button in this case) via the callback method, onRequestPermissionsResult(), which is responsible for checking if the permission is granted or not right after making a request as follows:

```
// Displays a permission dialog when requested for devices M and above.
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMS_REQUEST_CAMERA) {

        // User accepts the permission(s).
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            v.startAnimation(animSlide);
            allowCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            w = 1;
        } else { // User denies the permission.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please grant the permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

... and for your manageCameraPerm() method:

```
private void manageCameraPerm() {

    // Requests permission for devices with versions Marshmallow (M)/API 23 or above.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                MY_PERMS_REQUEST_CAMERA); // Invokes onRequestPermissionsResult()

            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: how can I use the view class in onRequestPermissionsResult ? I'm referring to v.startAnimation(animSlide);

Comment: @makkhaygurung Just simply instantiate a Button member variable/field (with ID: cameraPerm) somewhere in your UI thread within the Activity class instead, and start the animation accordingly :-)

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. The button is already instantiated in fragment class and I had already set up onClick listener there.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the if statement checking if the permission is granted happens right after the popup appears (and the permission has not been granted yet, of course). You need to trigger your animation in onPermissionResult (please see section "Handle the permissions request response" here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Haha you are right. That was a silly mistake. Guess what? I had included the toast message in onPermissionResult and I was trying the grant scenario somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

working with premission in android is not so simple . there is some library that make it easier like this:  https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher
just use this library!